# get urls of firefox tabs from firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

In a firefox extension, how do you enumerate the current window's tabs and retrieve their URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a code snippet at [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Tabbed_browser#Enumerating_tabs) that does exactly that:

```js
var num = gBrowser.browsers.length;
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  var b = gBrowser.getBrowserAtIndex(i);
  try {
    dump(b.currentURI.spec); // dump URLs of all open tabs to console
  } catch(e) {
    Components.utils.reportError(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: downvote, because you should add the code snippet to your answer.

Comment: Link is dead. This is exactly why we shouldn't do link only answers.

Comment: fixed the link for now.

Answer (score 1):

When using Firefox SDK, see this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/List_Open_Tabs

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
for (let tab of tabs)
    console.log(tab.url);
```

Additionally, the `tabs` object seems to have array interface, so you can use also the `.length` property:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    console.log(tabs[i].url);
```