# Chrome Tab duplicate not making network request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, window

I have 3 api calls on application load (componentDidMount).

When I reload the page or open the new tab, all the api calls are made but on duplicating the tab only one of them is fired.

How do I trigger all the api calls on page duplication

Note:
Browser: chrome.

Comment: Can you provide minimal [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: Maybe you have some if condition before your request. Something like if(cookies.yourSavedVariable){ doRequest() } first page makes your condition true and the request isn't executed

Comment: If the requests are the exact same, then chrome might chose to use cached responses instead of making new requests. That could be why you're not seeing any network activity.

Comment: This should give you some hints to explore: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752524/uniquely-identify-a-duplicated-chrome-tab

Answer (score 0):

use Memopromise tools its an effective tool to handle asynchronous processes.

```
class MemoPromise {

 constructor(getPromise) {

   this.cache = {};

   this.getPromise = getPromise;

   this.request = this.request.bind(this);

 }

 request({ uniqueKey, ...rest }) {

   if (!uniqueKey) {

     return Promise.reject(new Error('Unique key not passed'));

   }

   if (this.cache[uniqueKey]) {

     return this.cache[uniqueKey];

   }

   const promise = this.getPromise(rest);

   this.cache[uniqueKey] = promise

     .then((res) => {

       delete this.cache[uniqueKey];

       return res;

     })

     .catch((err) => {

       delete this.cache[uniqueKey];

       throw err;

     });

   return this.cache[uniqueKey];

 }

}
```

In the above example, I have created a MemoPromise class whose instantiated object can memorize the promises returned by the passed function in the constructor till the time they are not resolved or rejected.

see execution code

```
const memoPromise = new MemoPromise(fn);

// invocation

const { request } = memoPromise;

request({ uniqueKey: url, apiType, url, payload });

// not required now

// fn({ apiType, url, payload });
```

after integrating the Memopromise class your browser you might not be getting face any problem with your API requests. it deals effectively with your duplicate requests.