# Open html link in new, named tab

Tags: html

I am trying to open some links in a new tab, however I'd like to be able to open the same link in the same tab, should it be clicked again.

For example:

```
<a href="foo/0001" target="foo">foo</a>
```

would open in a new tab and

```
<a href="bar/0001" target="bar">bar</a>
```

would open in another new tab
however should I then click

```
  <a href="foo/0002" target="foo">foo</a>
```

I would want to open this in the tab I previously opened with the target of foo.

Comment: you can start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896160/any-way-to-identify-browser-tab-in-javascript

Comment: I would rather not use jQuery, is this not possible with html alone?

Comment: @pgGriff  I don't understand the question. The behaviour you say you desire is the behaviour the code you wrote in your question gives.

Comment: omg it actually is. Wow, ok, I'll carry on as normal then.